# How do I install Sphinx on a CentOs 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, centos

Newbie here..

Hello there I want to install [sphinx search](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads.html) to my CentOS 5.5.

I just need to know the commands, for the full installation.
If you could write a simple numbered manual that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rpm -ivh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum install sphinx
```

Comment: It isn't working. I get an error saying 'No package sphix available.'

Comment: Is it possible to replace that link with one of the links from the sphinx website download page?

Comment: new URL for this download is
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx Technologies distributes their software as RPM packages specifically built for CentOS/Redhat. See http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/

Comment: Then you can run "yum localinstall path/to/downloaded.rpm" to install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using x64, do this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```